# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when training more than one Keras NN models

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, segmentation-fault, keras, nvidia-jetson

I am optimizing the hyper-parameters of my neural-network, for which I am recursively training the network using different hyper-parameters. It works as expected until after some iterations, when creating a new network for training, it dies with the error "`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`".

Furthermore, I am using GPU for training and I am doing this on a Nvidia Jetson TX2 and Python3.5. Also, I am using Keras with TensorFlow backend.

Comment: If you can post the error stack, it would be easier for us to help you

Comment: The thing is it just dies, it does not print anything else besides that

Comment: Actually I used gdb and obtained  this: Thread 1 "python3.5" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000007f9ece1174 in tensorflow::TF_SessionReleaseCallable(TF_Session*, long, TF_Status*) () from /home/nvidia/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run K.clearsession() on a GPU with Keras 2, you may get a segmentation fault.
If you have this in your code, try removing it!

Comment: I did in fact have one on my code, but after removing it, I obtained the same result

Comment: I found a second hidden K.clearsession(), after removing it, it works now! Thank you for your help